# Display Gridview based on two dropdown value selection for two or more Id

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, gridview, aspxgridview

I have a two dropdown values when i select one dropdown and leave another dropdown blank the gridView should be displayed based on one dropdown selection. I am able to display this based on dropdown value selection but i have two ID in that table instead of id i need to display its name which is there in different table.

```
 <div class="form-group">
    <asp:Label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" runat="server" Text="Customer Name"></asp:Label>
         <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
              <asp:DropDownList ID="customerDetails" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" CssClass="mydropdownlist">
               <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Value="0">--Select Customer--</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:DropDownList>
     </div>
  </div>

   <div class="form-group">
     <asp:Label class="control-label col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-12" runat="server" Text="Sales Executive"></asp:Label>
       <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
            <asp:DropDownList ID="salesExceutive" runat="server" class="form-control col-md-7 col-xs-12" CssClass="mydropdownlist">
                 <asp:ListItem Enabled="true" Value="0">--Select Sales Executive--</asp:ListItem>
            </asp:DropDownList>
       </div>
   </div>

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" class="btn btn-primary"
         runat="server" Text="Search" OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />



 protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           if (customerText != "0" && salesExeText == "0")
            {

            string sqlQuery = @"SELECT *, app_user.first_name, app_customer.customer_name INNER JOIN app_customer ON app_order_master.customer_id = " + customerText + ")";

            using (DataTable dt = SMSDBHelperFE.ExecuteReaderDataTable(CommandType.Text, sqlQuery, null))
            {

                GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                GridView1.DataBind();                    
            }
          }
        }
```

[image]

this is my sql table i am getting this result but instead of customer id and user id, i need to display their name which is there in their tables.

Comment: You need to join the table that contains the ID and name with you current table.

Comment: can you help me with the query i know to join only two tables but i need to join 3 tables here

Comment: See following : https://www.interfacett.com/blogs/multiple-joins-work-just-like-single-joins/

Comment: but using this we can display all values i need only based on my customer selection

Comment: Then the query needs a WHERE (along with the join) to only select certain rows from the database.